# This ASP (C#) form code won't compile, new and not understanding what's going on

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm new to C# and ASP, and I'm trying to create a very basic form that performs a calculation. However, before I actually implement the calculation part, I'm just trying to do a simple test of the form by making it change the name of a button and nothing else. However, my code isn't compiling and I don't really understand why. If I'm making an obvious mistake please forgive me, I'm just trying to make a simple application here and I've barely done anything with C# or ASP before.
So, I have an HTML form (which has the button, form fields, etc.) with the only reference to the c# code being:

```
   <asp:Button id="calculate"
       Text="Calculate"
       OnClick="CalculateBtn_Calculate" 
       runat="server"/>
```

which is placed after the (currently unused and un-referenced) form fields. Basically even though I'm going to add an event that calculates it, for now I just have the button code. The only problem is my test code doesn't compile and me being new I don't know why.
My C# code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Main
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateBtn_Calculate += new EventHandler(this.CalculateBtn.Click);
}
void CalculateBtn_Calculate(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    clickedButton.Text = "...button clicked...";
    clickedButton.Enabled = false;

}

}
```

and the errors I get when I compile are:

> Error 5   'ASP.default_aspx' does not implement interface member
>   'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable'  c:\Users[censored]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\ab2ef4aa\781a850f\App_Web_lvhfdmq2.0.cs    172
>
> Error 3   'ASP.default_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found
>   to override   c:\Users[censored]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\ab2ef4aa\781a850f\App_Web_lvhfdmq2.0.cs    538
>
> Error 4   'ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)': no
>   suitable method found to
>   override  c:\Users[censored]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\ab2ef4aa\781a850f\App_Web_lvhfdmq2.0.cs    543
>
> Error 2   'ASP.default_aspx.SupportAutoEvents': no suitable method found
>   to override   c:\Users[censored]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\ab2ef4aa\781a850f\App_Web_lvhfdmq2.0.cs    199
>
> Error 6   'Main' does not contain a definition for 'CalculateBtn' and no
>   extension method 'CalculateBtn' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Main' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly
>   reference?)   C:\aspnet\XEx02Quotation\Default.aspx.cs    14  57  XEx02Quotation
>
> Error 1   Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or
>   UserControl). C:\aspnet\XEx02Quotation\Default.aspx.cs    8   33  XEx02Quotation

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: remove this line CalculateBtn_Calculate += new EventHandler(this.CalculateBtn.Click); in your page_load event. kindly put your aspx markup too, the upper part before the html tag will do.

Comment: Removed that line, still fails to build. <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

Comment: Could you please put your errors into codeblocks?

Comment: asp-classic never used C#. Are you absolutely sure that it is the tag you are looking for (by sample looks like asp.net)

Comment: Yes, it should be asp.net. I'll fix that now

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning the event from the back-end, then you need not to specify the `OnClick="CalculateBtn_Calculate"` in your mark-up. and you are assign an event to a method instead for that assign a method to an event. See the code below:

Asp Code:

```
<asp:Button id="CalculateBtn" Text="Calculate" runat="server"/>
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CalculateBtn.Click += new EventHandler(CalculateBtn_Calculate);
}
```

Comment: IT is working fine in my machine, Could you please confirm that Id of the button And `this.**CalculateBtn**.Click` are same